# Why does editing in QTreeView get initiated by other triggers than the one I have enabled?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I have enabled only the [SelectedClicked](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum) edit trigger in [QTreeView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtreeview.html), but item editing (via the [edit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#edit-2) method) is still getting triggered for other reasons (e.g., `CurrentChanged`). Why are other triggers active?

See the program below for an example, when clicking the tree items you should see that editing gets triggered for several different reasons:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class TreeView(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setEditTriggers(self.SelectedClicked)

        self.__model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.__model.appendRow([QStandardItem('Item 1')])
        self.__model.appendRow([QStandardItem('Item 2')])
        self.setModel(self.__model)

    def edit(self, index, trigger, event):
        print('Edit index {},{}, trigger: {}'.format(index.row(), index.column(), trigger))
        return False


app = QApplication([])
w = TreeView()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit will always be called, whatever EditTrigger you use. However, depending on the trigger you specify, it is the edit slot job to create or not an editor, and to return true or false (see [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#edit-2)). In your code, edit do nothing (and the item don't get edited since no editor is created). Try calling `super().edit(self, index, trigger, event)`.

```
def edit(self, index, trigger, event):
    res = super().edit(index, trigger, event)
    print('Edit {},{}, trigger: {}, accepted: {}'.format(index.row(), index.column(), trigger, res))
    return res
```

Comment: So you're saying that `edit` gets called independent of `editTriggers()`, but `edit` ignores non-selected triggers?

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand, that's pretty much it.